# concatenate two data frames and add a tag column to differentiate in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames as shown below

df1:

```
Name        Age       goals
Messi       31        500
Suarez      35        300
Xavi        39        100
```

df2:

```
Name        Age       goals
Benzema     33        400
Kroos       30        100
```

I would like to concatenate this two and new one with an extra column club as shown below.

df_concate:

```
Name        Age       goals    club
Messi       31        500      barcelona
Suarez      35        300      barcelona
Xavi        39        100      barcelona
Benzema     33        400      realmadrid
Kroos       30        100      realmadrid
```

I tried below code:

```
pieces = {'barcelona': df1, 'realmadrid': df2}
df_concate = pd.concat(pieces)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close...

```
pieces = {'barcelona': df1, 'realmadrid': df2}
df_concate = pd.concat(pieces, names=['club'])
df_concate = df_concate.reset_index(level=0)
df_concate
```

Output:

```
         club     Name  Age  goals
0   barcelona    Messi   31    500
1   barcelona   Suarez   35    300
2   barcelona     Xavi   39    100
0  realmadrid  Benzema   33    400
1  realmadrid    Kroos   30    100
```

Comment: nice use of `names` in concat, I was thinking using `rename_axis` for same result, way shorter like this

Answer (score 2):

[`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the new column before `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1.assign(club='barcelona'), df2.assign(club='realmadrid')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

frames = [a,b]

frames[0]['club'] = 'Barcelona'
frames[1]['club'] = 'RealMadrid'

df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @pppery I read both the data frames, put them into a list (frames), added a column 'club' in the two dataframes inside the list and then concatenated.